# Android app not being able to find an external library and R file

Tags: java, android, android-library, r.java-file

So I have an android app and added a third party library to it. The code will compile fine, however, when I get to where methods of that library are, the program will stop with a bunch of errors starting with

```
    W/XWalkInternalResources(10703): org.xwalk.core.R$string.color_picker_button_cya
n is not found.
```

(and similiar messages with all the other things in the R file)

and then

```
I/LibraryLoader(10703): Loading: xwalkcore
D/dalvikvm(10703): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/org.yaxim.androidclient-2/li
bxwalkcore.so 0x430ba840
D/dalvikvm(10703): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/org.yaxim.androidclient-2/libx
walkcore.so 0x430ba840
W/System.err(10703): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/xwalk/core/AndroidProto
colHandler
W/System.err(10703):    at java.lang.Runtime.nativeLoad(Native Method)
W/System.err(10703):    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:379)
W/System.err(10703):    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
W/System.err(10703):    at org.chromium.base.library_loader.LibraryLoader.loadAl
readyLocked(LibraryLoader.java:139)
```

I've doubled checked everything from the buildpath to the dependencies in the properties. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to clean your project ?

(Project > Clean...)